# Replacing DataFrame column values - the column row data stored as list

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, lambda

I would greatly appreciate contributions on how to solve this puzzle,
I have this dataFrame with the structure below in the snapshot, I am trying to replace the values in the Hobbies column with values from this list(myList) that are currently not present in each row of the Hobbies column
[image]

```
myList =["Dancing","Climbing,"Singing"]
```

This is what I have tried, And I seems to be far from the right solution.

```
df.apply(lambda x:df['Hobbies'],(for i in myList: if i not in x : x.append(i)))
```

Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the syntax of the lambda function.

The correct code is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["coe","wood","silla"],
                    "color":["yellow","green","white"],
                    "hobbies":[["swimming","reading"],
                                ["dancing","reading"],
                                ["driving","reading"]
                                ]})

a=["dancing","climbing","singing"]

df["hobbies"]=df["hobbies"].apply(lambda x: x + [i for i in a if i not in x])
```

In this case, you should apply the function only to one column, so you replace the current column with the new one.

Hope it works!

Comment: your contribution was super helpful,  Another scenario to the case above is that if there are empty list in the rows and I want to replace such row with the entire  list  a=["dancing","climbing","singing"]

    a=["dancing","climbing","singing"] 

what lambda approach would be better. 
This is an approach , I am trying                                                                                                                                                                           
   df["hobbies"]=df["hobbies"].apply(lambda x: [a for i in x if i is None else x] )

Comment: If what you have in the cell is an empty list, the code I send before should still work, because an empty list would not have any of the items `["dancing","climbing","singing"]` so the cell will be filled with the complete list. On the other hand, if what you have in your cell is a NoneType object, i.e. `None`, you have to do a little modification to the original line I send: `df["hobbies"]=df["hobbies"].apply(lambda x: x + [i for i in a if i not in x] if x is not None else a)`. Let me know if that's what you meant.

Comment: Thanks Matias for contributions, really super helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

-Replace a single value with a new value for an individual DataFrame column:

```py
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['old value'],'new value')
```

-Replace multiple values with a new value for an individual DataFrame column:

```py
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['1st old value','2nd old value',...],'new value')
```

-Replace multiple values with multiple new values for an individual DataFrame column:

```py
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['1st old value','2nd old value',...],['1st new value','2nd new value',...])
```

-Replace a single value with a new value for an entire DataFrame:

```py
df = df.replace(['old value'],'new value')
```